# Boost.Asio without Boost.System

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, stl, boost-asio

On the [Boost System page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/system/doc/index.html) it is stated that:

> The Boost System Library is part of the C++11 Standard Library.

But a number of Boost libraries, such as Asio, depend on Boost System. Is it possible to use the C++11 std stuff instead of Boost System to work with Asio?

Comment: What is the goal? Would be helpful if mentioned.

Comment: Boost.System is not header-only and needs to be compiled. This is for a multiplatform project and avoiding having to build Boost.System would be nice (for Android and iOS mostly).

Comment: Like this? https://think-async.com/Asio/AsioStandalone

Comment: That could be an option, but I also want to use Boost.Beast, which depends on Boost.Asio. BOOST_ERROR_CODE_HEADER_ONLY solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

AFAIR you can configure Boost System to be header-only

[image]

Source: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/system/doc/reference.html

Other than that, you might simply use [Non-Boost Asio](https://think-async.com/Asio/Download)

Comment: BOOST_ERROR_CODE_HEADER_ONLY solves the issue! Thank you.