# boost::asio installation via minGW64

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, mingw-w64

I downloaded mingw64 compiler and boost 1.69.0.
I started bootstrap.bat from cmd with command "bootstrap gcc". then compilation I installed it with command "b2 toolset=gcc --prefix=C:/boost install".

After I looked for asio and saw, that there were only headers (in "include" dir). But there were no libs (.a) of asio.

Can someone tell me why those libs didn't compiled, and what I need to do to compile them?

For example library 'filesystem' successfuly compiled and works.

Comment: Asio is only header library, see [this link](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/more/getting_started/windows.html),caption - *header only libraries*, the list contains all binary libraries, *asio* is not listed there.

Comment: @rafix07, thank you.

Comment: @rafix07 `boost::asio` is a header only library but it depends upon `boost::system` unless a macro has been set, see: [Boost.Asio without Boost.System](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49418493/boost-asio-without-boost-system). So an executable using `asio` normally requires`boost::system` when linking.